# Cost per acquisition in GA Event from Adwords campaigns?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I've created an Event on Google Analytics to count all new sign-ups on my website, then I've created a goal on Google Analytics that gets results from that Event so I can send this goal to my Google Adwords account to trace conversion rate from my campaigns.

The problem that I have is manually calculating the cost of acquisition as in Google Analytics Goal value showing 0 where I set Goal Value as Event Value

On Adwords, I've set Value to be managed by Google Analytics.

How does one set the Event value to reflect my Adwords campaign (as each click has it's own CPC value)?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a couple of different concepts.

CPC = Cost/Clicks and is this is recalculated with each click on your ads and changes mostly due to competitions.
Value = Constant monetary value, say, 50 USD which you need to assign based on business logic for your site. E.g. the average customer's lifetime value less the average cost of acquisition.

Note: if you are getting 0 value for the events you have an issue with how you have coded your event. You should post the code snippet you are using.

anyhow the analytics code you need to use is:

> ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue]);

or more specifically something like:

```js
var regVal=myCPCcalculator();
ga('send', 'event', 'macro_conversions', 'click', 'registration', regVal]);
```

Comment: I noticed that in GA event you can choose fixed value I want to calculate actual value of each conversion,for example if I paid 50$ and get 10 Clicks so CPC=5$ But if 2 Converted so Conversion value will be 25$, how can I pull actual value
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        jQuery('.site-signup .btn').click(function(){
               $dataname = $(this).data('role');
               var label= 'create my account ('+$(this).data('role')+')';
               ga('send','event','button','click','create my ');
           })        
           })
    </script>

Comment: I've added the event tracking code you need to be using to the comment above

Comment: what is "myCPCcalculator();" is predefined function on GA or I should include it to the code and how it's functionality ?

Comment: that where you would get or calculate the CPC.  CPC is defined for keyword or banners - you need to decide what number you want to use and how to get it. AFAIK The CPC is not available in real time but you can get most of the details this way: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?hl=en&ref_topic=6031980 . This should allow you to setup different CPC using the ad/campaign parameters.